# Switching between ARKit marker based scenes crashes app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm currently trying to switch between different scenes with ARKit, I have 3 markerless scenes and 3 marker based scenes. The problem is however that when switching from one marker based scene to another crashes the app and gives a SIGABRT error in xcode.

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, [NSString stringWithUTF8String: AppControllerClassName]);
```

I was having the same issue earlier on with switching between markerless scenes, but I finally figured how to fix it by resetting the scene like this:

```
public void ResetScene()
   {
       ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration(UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity, UnityARPlaneDetection.Horizontal);
       UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().RunWithConfigAndOptions(sessionConfig, UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking);
   }
```

I think I need to reset the imageanchor scenes (marker based) to fix the crash between switching scenes, but I have no clue how to reset the marker based scenes, since this seems to need a different reset.

The way I'm currently loading scenes is as follows;

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Marker", LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

This part fires when certain conditions are met (the marker/markerless toggle and the name of the scene). This is all working correctly in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

There was a crash issue when switching scenes (and resetting the AR Session) in an older version of the ARKit package. The issue should be fixed when you update to a newer version of ARKit.

Check out this thread for more info:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/app-crashes-after-arsession-reset.570763/

Editing for visibility: 
iPad crashes on switching AR Scene could be fixed by updating Unity: github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/94

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, but I'm already using the latest ARKit version in my project, so this can't be the case.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: An iPad pro (2018)

Comment: I remember a crash on iPad when switching AR Scene too. I fixed it by updating my Unity to 2018.3.7 (or later) after seeing this thread: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/94